# WatchKit – Two tables in two pages, second page has first couple of rows super-narrow

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I have the following setup in my `WatchKit` app:

- Two horizontal pages, which are configured programmatically via `reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:`
- Each page contains a `WKInterfaceTable` which loads some separate data.

What I’m noticing is that the second page’s table has its content pushed down so that the first row in the right table is positioned somewhere in-between the second and third rows of the left table.

If I load a single table and a single page, everything is fine with either set of content, this issue only occurs when I have two pages, and both pages have a table – the second page has its table positioned low.

Both pages are using the same `WKInterfaceController` and pretty much identical logic (they’re just loading two sets of data), so I’m not sure why this might be happening.

It’s also worth noting that if I set up the two pages inside the storyboard and link them by dragging and using the “next page” segue, the problem still happens, so it’s not being caused by using `reload`.

This image shows mid-pan between the left and right page, and shows the gap on the right one (and that weird red stripe occurs twice, and my gut is telling me that it’s setting the width of my first two rows to like, 1 pixel or something).

[image]

Any idea what’s going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was doing the table config in `AwakeWithContent()`. When I moved it to `WillAppear()` it worked fine. I think the problem is that as you are swiping to the scene it is trying to position the table.

`WillAppear()` seems to occur once the scene has slid in.

Comment: Hmm, that’s a tricky one. Does your `context` in the awake method not contain the info for your table? Mine does. I wonder if it’s worth opening a radar.

Comment: Should not be a problem. Make sure you store the data in an instance variable, and use it in willActivate